Outlook Add-in Installation failed
I want to add support for mobile in an existing outlook add-in, so I added in the manifest (on top of the existing addin that gets installed successfully) this tag:
 <MobileFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
              <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="mblReadFunctionButton">
                  <Label resid="funcReadButtonLabel" />

                  <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon32" />

                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon32" />

                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon32" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
        </MobileFormFactor>

I verified the xml with office-addin-manifest validate and the manifest is valid, anyways, when I upload it I get "Add-in instalation failed". What am I doing wrong?
I tried to manually install an add in from Outlook -> Manage add ins, but I came over an installation error
